# Resize2fs not working?

Tags: centos6

I have a disk (/dev/sda)
It has the following partition table:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        50G  6.1G   41G  13% /
tmpfs           7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       976M  147M  779M  16% /boot
/dev/sda4       197G   41G  147G  22% /vz
```

/dev/sda4 had 400G and I shrinked it with resize2fs to 200G
But I can't find the unallocated space?

df -h showed me the above results but when i do parted and then print all it shows me this:

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary  ext4            boot
 2      1075MB  54.8GB  53.7GB  primary  ext4
 3      54.8GB  71.9GB  17.2GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 4      71.9GB  500GB   428GB   primary  ext4
```

It still has it's old size.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have done nothing wrong. Shrinking the filesystem has no effect on the underlying partition. You will need to use parted or fdisk etc to edit the partition table.

Comment: Well, could you provide me more information on what to do now? I need to create a other partition with the unallocted space what I just shrinked :)

Comment: You are not playing your part of the game. You now know what you  need to do so you should go away and research that In this respect google and the docs are your friend. If you become truly stuck then, after researching you should ask a new question showing your research etc. 10 minutes is insufficient time for you to have done any research.

Comment: I understeand! But I can't find anything. Only to remove the whole partition and create a new one? I now understeand that I shrinked the filesystem and not the partition.